# modal boostrap abre e fecha sozinho

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, modal

Estou com um problema no meu modal bootstrap. Ele é o mais simples possivel, peguei o exemplo do próprio site do bootstrap para testá-lo porém quando clico no botao, ele abre e fecha logo em seguida automaticamente

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal" id="botao_pedido">Faça seu pedido</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Olá
        </div>

    </div><!--modal-content-->
</div><!--modal-dialog-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei as libs que o próprio Bootstrap propõem e coloquei seu modal e funcionou normalmente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal" id="botao_pedido">Faça seu pedido</button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Olá
                    </div>
                </div> <!--modal-content-->
            </div> <!--modal-dialog-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Matheus, beleza? Dê uma checada no console do seu navegador.
Provavelmente está reclamando algum import que não tenha sido feito.
Lembre-se que o bootstrap.js depende do jQuery para funcionar.
Pode ser algo neste sentido!

Comment: Console ta normal

Comment: Os 3 imports estão sendo feitos? (bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js e bootstrap.min.js).
Se estiverem, teste em outro navegador.

Comment: Apenas complementando... eu rodei sem problemas o seu exemplo aqui no meu navegador (firefox). Versões 3.3.7 do bootstrap e jquery 1.12.4

Comment: Estão sim, consegui resolver a situação mas obrigado pela atenção ao problema

Answer (score 0):

Li em uns foruns gringos que o problema geralmente é na inserção dos arquivos javascript do bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

é aconselhavel usar apenas o bootstrap.js ou bootstrap.min.js pois ja inclui ele

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, porém descobri em meu código que tinha havia duas declarações do bootstrap

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Mantive apenas uma e funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Meu caso era igual o Lucas.
Haviam duas declaração do arquivo.js do bootstrap,   removi o da versão mais antiga e funciona muito bem agora.